# How to properly use the @SelectFile annotation in a Unit 5 test class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5

I am writing unit tests for a java class where I need to pass a file as a parameter. I recently came across the `@SelectFile` annotation in `Spring Boot`, which seems like a good solution for my use case. However, I am not sure how to use it properly. I am using `junit 5` and `Spring Boot` framework.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```java
@SelectFile(value = "/file.json")
class DataFormatTest {
    @Test
    void formatTest() throws Exception {
        Format format = new Format();
        //format.formatFile(file.json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@ParametrizedTest` and `@MethodSource` for your purpose.
For ex

```java
class SomeTest {

    public static Stream<Arguments> getFiles() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.arguments(new File("/file.json")),
                Arguments.arguments(new File("/file2.json")));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFiles")
    void doTest(File file) {
        assertFalse(file.exists());
    }
}
```

`@SelectFile` annotation is not for your issue.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a brief explanation of the appropriate use cases for the "@SelectFile"?

Comment: @TaneeZ as far as i understood according to `junit` documentation it was used(perhaps still uses) for working with different test runners before `junit jupiter` was created. So it is used for selecting test units to run(i may mistake). So if you need to test some of class sending him a file(or some other test data) you may use `@ParametrizedTest`. Here is a good article about it https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5